# Where is graph.h in the fltk 1.3 library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, fltk

I installed FTLK on my compiler as instructed in Stroustrup's (programming principles and practice using c++). The examples in the book uses two headers, seen below, which are not being found by the compiler. Anyone know how I can include these headers? The book is a few years old and mentions FLTK 1.1, but FLTK is currently 1.3.

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>  
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
#include <FL\Fl_Single_Window.H>
#include "Simple_window.h"//error
#include "Graph.h"//error


int main(int argc, char **argv)   
{  
Point tl(100,100);//error class not found

}
```

Comment: They should be mentioned in the book you're reading(either where to download them or the source per se)

Comment: does using #include <> or #include "" make a difference?

Comment: they affect order the compiler searches for files, but generally it is used as a convention - <> for library headers, "" for your own

Comment: In this example, unless you added include paths to your project, compiler expects those files in the same directory the .cpp file is

Comment: Based on what you are telling me, it seems that Stroustrup may have written those header files specifically for this book and they may be lurking somewhere on his website...:( hmmmmm

Comment: that was exactly right. I found all the code on Stroustrup's webpage. He mentions to include those files, but never says it's not included in FLTK, because he wrote them,and you need to copy paste them from his website.

Comment: It is a bit obvious that they are not part of FLTK.  All the FLTK headers have the pattern FL/...h

Answer (score 1):

Look at here (http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/) and download the *Complete collection of code fragments (revised)*, Then unzip this and add all the GUI folder's header files into your *include* (in C:....) directory and run the code again.